# how to I match a url with post's variables

Tags: regex, nginx, pcre

How do I match the url as belows with PCRE:

1. `http://www.test.com/abc?v=123&feature=True`
2. `http://www.test.com/def?v=456&feature=True`

What I'm going to do is to match the path(abc or def) under a domain,
so that I can redirect the request to a specify host using nginx.

```
        #content of /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
             location / {
               #default redirect
                proxy_pass http://www.google.com;

               #redirect by domain name.
               if ($path ~* abc)
               {
                       proxy_pass http://10.1.1.47:8081?v=123&feature=True;
               }
               if ($path ~* edf)
               {
                       proxy_pass http://10.1.1.48:8081?v=456&feature=True;
               }
             }
```

PS: the domain and the path are not restricted to www.test.com and (abc|def), respectively.

thanks!

Comment: what do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://www.google.com;
}

location /abc/ {
    proxy_pass http://10.1.1.47:8081?v=123&feature=True;
}

location /edf/ {
    proxy_pass http://10.1.1.48:8081?v=456&feature=True;
}
```